# UIImageView not showing in UI.

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have an imageview which is not showing up on the UI.

Here is how I connect the outlet in my header:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *buttonPointsImageView;
```

[image]

What could be the problem? I am using a xib file with xcode 5.

Comment: probably another view is above your uiimageview

Comment: I tried     [successView bringSubviewToFront:successView.buttonPointsImageView] but it does not work.

Comment: add a screenshot from the view stack from the .xib here.

Comment: What's its frame (at runtime), try by setting its backgroundColor (with yellow for example or something you'll see easily).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the auto resize. it was resizing from top left and so was not showing in the place I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have synthesised the outlet and are referring it by self.nameofOutlet.

Answer (score 0):

Please check auto layout of your iboutlets.